# Anchor IDL address missing from json

Tags: anchor, idl, anchor-program-idl

Is it just me or did the `"metadata": {"address: Pubkey}` key-value pair from the generated json disappear when running `anchor build`?

Comment: Never mind, I think it is a false alarm

Comment: It's not a false alarm. It reminds you to deploy Solana Program first before using idl.json file somewhere else such as with the frontend code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"metadata": {"address": "pubKey"}` may disappear when running `anchor build` you will get it back once you run `anchor deploy`.