# Error: IDL for program `loss_harvester` does not have `metadata.address` field

Tags: anchor, anchor-test, idl

When running anchor test on my solana program it complains that the IDL is missing the metadata.address field. But when I add it, it disappears again after running anchor test. My program built fine.

Also, the field "metadata" gives an error: "Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"metadata"' does not exist in type LossHarvester"

I also tried adding it then running anchor deploy as per this post:
[Anchor IDL address missing from json](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3868/anchor-idl-address-missing-from-json)

```
export const IDL: LossHarvester = {
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "name": "loss_harvester",
  "metadata": {
    "address": "[PROGRAM_PUB_KEY]"
  },
...rest of code
```

Beginning of my program:

```
#[program]
pub mod loss_harvester {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
```

Am I missing something here? Using anchor 0.29 with Solana 1.18.1. Something to note is that I started out with the hello-world template and renamed everything to loss-harvester.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED. I forgot to update the program name in one of the fields in Cargo.toml

Answer (score -1):

export const IDL: LossHarvester = {
"version": "0.1.0",
"name": "loss_harvester",
"metadata": {
"address": "[PROGRAM_PUB_KEY]"
},
...rest of code
#[program]
pub mod loss_harvester {
use super::*;

```
pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
```